# Apache conf on Ubuntu causing url to repeat itself instead of redirect

Tags: apache, server, virtualhost, certbot

Ubuntu 18.04
Apache2
Certbot

I'm trying to get cerbot and non-www to www redirects set up on this site and I am copying the conf file from another one of my sites that is working just fine, but for some reason 443 is forbidden to the user on this new site and non-www.domain.url redirects to domain.url/www.domain.urlwww.domain.urlwww.domain.url etc.

main.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                 
    ServerName domain.url                                                                                       
    Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.url/                                                         
</VirtualHost>   

<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    ServerName www.domain.url                                                                                    
    ServerAdmin email@domain.url                                                                              
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
                                                                                                                                                                                         
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log          
                                                                                                                                                                       
    RewriteEngine on                                                                                           
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.url                                                                  
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]                            
</VirtualHost>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

main-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>                                                                                             
    <VirtualHost *:443>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        ServerName www.domain.url                                                                                          
        ServerAdmin email@domain.url                                                                                 
        ServerAlias domain.url                                                                                            
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html 
        
        RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]                                                                            
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log                                                                             
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined   
                                                                                                                                                                                   
        Alias /static /home/user/project/static                                                                     
        <Directory /home/user/project/static>                                                                               
            Require all granted                                                                                      
        </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

        <Directory /home/user/project/media>                                                                                
            Require all granted                                                                                      
        </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

        <Directory /home/user/project>                                                                                      
            <Files wsgi.py>                                                                                                          
                Require all granted                                                                                      
            </Files>                                                                                                 
        </Directory>   
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project/project/wsgi.py                                                          
        WSGIDaemonProcess theprocess python-path=/home/user/prject python-home=/home/user/project/wow           
        WSGIProcessGroup theprocess                                                                                                                                                                                                 

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf                                                                 
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.url/fullchain.pem                                              
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.url/privkey.pem                                             
    </VirtualHost>                                                                                                   
</IfModule>
```

ssh, http, https are all enabled with ufw. I might have a permissions issue with users being able to view my site, but it was working fine until certbot was installed. now everything (except non-https non-www which causes the repeating domain issue) redirects to https://www.domain.url and I get a forbidden message.

When I installed certbot I missed the non-www domain. when I went back and renewed to get both www and non-www the redirect setup failed but it said I had my certs. Is this causing the issue? I thought I could just build the redirect myself in the config file...

Answer (score 0):

This post ended up being the answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/957788/forbidden-after-enabling-ssl

I had a case error in my WSGIScriptAlias file path.